# Get mutable reborrow in a closure

Tags: rust

The minimal reproducible example:

```
struct A {
    x: i32,
}

impl A {
    fn do_A(&mut self) {
        self.x = 1;
    }
    fn do_B(&mut self) {
        self.x = 2;
    }
    fn do_A_and_something(&mut self, mut something: impl FnMut()) {
        self.do_A();
        something();
    }

    fn do_A_and_B(&mut self) {
        self.do_A();
        self.do_B();
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut a = A { x: 0 };

    // a.do_A_and_B(); // this works
    a.do_A_and_something(|| a.do_B()); // this is equivalent to the one above but doesn't work
}
```

I get why the `do_A_and_something` version doesn't work.  I'm mutably borrowing `a` twice, first in creating the closure and second in calling the function `a.do_A_and_something`.  I also (sort of) understand understand why the `do_A_and_B` version works (I believe it has something to do with reborrowing).

My question is, given that these two are equivalent, is there some way to get reborrowing to work within the closure?

Comment: Note: `&mut self` doesn't just mean you can mutate self, it also means that *every* access to parts of `self` can *only* be through that parameter. That excludes the other parameter (`something`) from having or allowing access to any bit of `self`.

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing the question, it dawned on me that I could get a reborrowed reference of `a` inside `do_A_and_something` but not in `main`.  Hence the following works, but only if you are able to modify `do_A_and_something`.

```
struct A {
    x: i32,
}

impl A {
    fn do_A(&mut self) {
        self.x = 1;
    }
    fn do_B(&mut self) {
        self.x = 2;
    }
    fn do_A_and_something(&mut self, mut something: impl FnMut(&mut A)) {
        self.do_A();
        something(self); // reborrow happening here!
    }

    fn do_A_and_B(&mut self) {
        self.do_A();
        self.do_B();
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut a = A { x: 0 };

    a.do_A_and_something(|a_reborrowed| a_reborrowed.do_B());
}
```